# Timer built in Unity using Async Await

Tags: c#, async-await, unity3d

For learning purposes, I built a timer that does something every x seconds in Unity using an async Task instead of a coroutine.

I'd like to know if there is a less awkward way of writing this:

What bothers me the most is that I need to check the task every frame in order to be able to cancel it at any moment, instead of using `task.Delay(timerDuration_s)`. So I have to write more logic to check when the timer has run out.

```
public class TimerBlock : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float timerDuration_s;
    private MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
    private BoxCollider boxCollider;

    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

    private void Awake()
    {
        meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task task = ToggleBlockAsync();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        meshRenderer.enabled = false;
        boxCollider.enabled = false;
    }

    private async Task ToggleBlockAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            float timer = 0f;

            while (true)
            {
                cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                if(timer >= timerDuration_s)
                {
                    meshRenderer.enabled = !meshRenderer.enabled;
                    boxCollider.enabled = !boxCollider.enabled;
                    timer = 0f;
                }

                timer += Time.deltaTime;

                await Task.Yield();
            }
        }

        catch(OperationCanceledException exception)
        {
            Debug.Log(exception.Message +  "ToggleBlock Task cancelled");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you would perform this check not at every frame rather than lets say every 60th frame?

Comment: The thing is, I check the timer every frame because I want to be able to cancel it immediately. If I check every second, I won't be able to do that.